# libuv: uv_queue_work() delay

Tags: c, latency, libuv

I'm using *libuv* and when calling `uv_queue_work(..., work_cb, after_work_cb)`, for some reason, *libuv* takes ~50ms to call `after_work_cb(...)` after the end of `work_cb(..)`, causing a significant latency overhead (testing on linux).

Is there a known workaround to substantially reduce this delay? Otherwise, I'll have to refactor the code to be synchronous, which would harm scalability, since `work_cb(...)` blocks for a couple of milliseconds, which it spends mostly on waiting for file system operations.

Comment: You need to demo the problem.

Comment: Are you saying that `work_cb` only takes a few milliseconds? And how long does `after_work_cb` take? (Tag the reply with `@ikegami`.)